# Get id by finding element from data in a dynamic html (jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get the ***element id*** during **scan barcode sku** event, and ***get element*** according to ***data-sku*** in the **li** which added dynamically under **UL** which loads from another function on load of page.

I tried many ways as guided but it looks i am missing some thing due to which i am unable to get desired result, following what i am trying is the last looks more relative.

**Data i have in UL added dynamically in another function on load**

```
<div class="inside" id="grid_layout_cycle" data-offset="0" data-parent="0" style="height: 382px;">
<ul>
    <li id="product_1886" class="title_product add_grid_tile category_cycle" data-sku="ORD_1879_1886" data-id="1886" data-root-category="[undefined]" title="_1879" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://impaktt.techchef.org/wp-content/themes/the-hanger/images/placeholder.png&quot;);"><span>_1879</span><span class="price">Free!</span></li>
    <li id="product_4538" class="title_product add_grid_tile category_cycle" data-sku="ORD_2604_4538" data-id="4538" data-root-category="[undefined]" title="_2604" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://impaktt.techchef.org/wp-content/themes/the-hanger/images/placeholder.png&quot;);"><span>_2604</span><span class="price">Free!</span></li>
    <li id="product_4051" class="title_product add_grid_tile category_cycle" data-sku="ORD_3932_4051" data-id="4051" data-root-category="[undefined]" title="_3932" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://impaktt.techchef.org/wp-content/themes/the-hanger/images/placeholder.png&quot;);"><span>_3932</span><span class="price">Free!</span></li>
</ul>
```

Lastly i have called following script to select element from *data-sku="ORD_3932_4051"* and log it into the console

```
var tempProductScan = $("#grid_layout_cycle ul").find("[data-sku='ORD_3932_4051']");
console.log(tempProductScan);
```

I got the below result in the log (its not complete array but a overview to understand),which seems not as it should be

```
0: <li id="product_4051" class="title_product add_grid_tile category_cycle" data-sku="ORD_3932_4051" data-id="4051" data-root-category="[undefined]" title="_3932" style="background-image: url(\"ages/placeholder.png\");">
context: HTMLDocument https://impaktt.techchef.org/point-of-sale/main-outlet/testing-new/#
length: 1
prevObject: Object { 0: ul, selector: "#grid_layout_cycle ul", length: 1, … }
selector: "#grid_layout_cycle ul [data-sku='ORD_3932_4051']"
<prototype>: Object { jquery: "1.12.4", constructor: n(a, b), length: 0, … }
```

And finally when i am trying to fetch **id** from this it does shows **undefined**

**Please Note:**
When i am only calling UL elements as below it gives all element in child nodes.

```
var tempProductScanParent = $("#grid_layout_cycle").find('ul');
console.log(tempProductScanParent);
```

**result for above i got in firefox is as below (its not complete as its large but to give you an idea)**

```
    {…}
    ​
    0: ul
    ​​
    accessKey: ""
    ​​
    accessKeyLabel: ""
    ​​
    accessibleNode: AccessibleNode { computedRole: "list", states: (4) […], attributes: (9) […], … }
    ​​
    assignedSlot: null
    ​​
    attributes: NamedNodeMap []
    ​​
    baseURI: "https://impaktt.techchef.org/point-of-sale/main-outlet/testing-new/#"
    ​​
    childElementCount: 50
    ​​
    childNodes: NodeList(50) [ li#product_1886.title_product.add_grid_tile.category_cycle, li#product_4538.title_product.add_grid_tile.category_cycle, li#product_4051.title_product.add_grid_tile.category_cycle
    , … ]
    ​​
    children: HTMLCollection { 0: li#product_1886.title_product.add_grid_tile.category_cycle, 1: li#product_4538.title_product.add_grid_tile.category_cycle, 2: li#product_4051.title_product.add_grid_tile.category_cycle
    , … }
    ​​
    classList: DOMTokenList [...
```

**The complete snippet you can see below:**

```js
var tempProductScan = $("#grid_layout_cycle ul").find("[data-sku='ORD_3932_4051']");
console.log(tempProductScan);

var tempProductScanParent = $("#grid_layout_cycle").find('ul');
console.log(tempProductScanParent);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inside" id="grid_layout_cycle" data-offset="0" data-parent="0" style="height: 382px;">
  <ul>
    <li id="product_1886" class="title_product add_grid_tile category_cycle" data-sku="ORD_1879_1886" data-id="1886" data-root-category="[undefined]" title="_1879" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://impaktt.techchef.org/wp-content/themes/the-hanger/images/placeholder.png&quot;);"><span>_1879</span><span class="price">Free!</span></li>
    <li id="product_4538" class="title_product add_grid_tile category_cycle" data-sku="ORD_2604_4538" data-id="4538" data-root-category="[undefined]" title="_2604" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://impaktt.techchef.org/wp-content/themes/the-hanger/images/placeholder.png&quot;);"><span>_2604</span><span class="price">Free!</span></li>
    <li id="product_4051" class="title_product add_grid_tile category_cycle" data-sku="ORD_3932_4051" data-id="4051" data-root-category="[undefined]" title="_3932" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://impaktt.techchef.org/wp-content/themes/the-hanger/images/placeholder.png&quot;);"><span>_3932</span><span class="price">Free!</span></li>
  </ul>
```

**Applied Changes as specified in comment**
I tried following with ***children()***

```
var tempProductScan = $("#grid_layout_cycle ul");
console.log($(tempProductScan[0]).children());
```

it gives following nodes but  not selecting specific element by ***data-sku***
https://i.ibb.co/JtpW0q7/image.png

> i am curious if there is a way to get the element from the array or
> object by key after finding specific data-sku of it

**Solution Found**

> As Mr @uingtea guided that , find the right selector via inspect
> element so i did that, and found it was mistake in the selector i used
> double quotes in inspect element and then apply same in script and it
> works.

```
var tempProductScan = $('#grid_layout_cycle ul li[data-sku="testing"]');

var SKU_ScanId = tempProductScan[0].id;
alert(theID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.find()` return array `[]` you need to define the index

```js
var tempProductScan = $("#grid_layout_cycle ul").find("[data-sku='ORD_3932_4051']");
var theID = tempProductScan[0].id;
console.log(theID);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inside" id="grid_layout_cycle" data-offset="0" data-parent="0" style="height: 382px;">
  <ul>
    <li id="product_1886" class="title_product add_grid_tile category_cycle" data-sku="ORD_1879_1886" data-id="1886" data-root-category="[undefined]" title="_1879" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://impaktt.techchef.org/wp-content/themes/the-hanger/images/placeholder.png&quot;);"><span>_1879</span><span class="price">Free!</span></li>
    <li id="product_4538" class="title_product add_grid_tile category_cycle" data-sku="ORD_2604_4538" data-id="4538" data-root-category="[undefined]" title="_2604" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://impaktt.techchef.org/wp-content/themes/the-hanger/images/placeholder.png&quot;);"><span>_2604</span><span class="price">Free!</span></li>
    <li id="product_4051" class="title_product add_grid_tile category_cycle" data-sku="ORD_3932_4051" data-id="4051" data-root-category="[undefined]" title="_3932" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://impaktt.techchef.org/wp-content/themes/the-hanger/images/placeholder.png&quot;);"><span>_3932</span><span class="price">Free!</span></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: unfortunately tempProductScan is not loading same as in static html data, See the attached image below it gives childelements under prevObject

https://i.ibb.co/jfd9p6n/image.png

Comment: I can't help without see complete html, can you create demo page or post it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: i tried with children(), it gives following nodes but not selecting specific element by data-sku ,
i am curious if there is a way to get the element from the array or object by key after finding specific data-sku of it. Here is the image of child object https://i.ibb.co/JtpW0q7/image.png

Comment: ok let me try to create page, but can you please tell me if there is a  way to get object/array key by finding specific data of its element that would help me, to try other way

Comment: to get the right selector, debug it in browser, press F12. see this image [browser console](https://i.postimg.cc/wj7k0C9S/volume.png)

Comment: your idea work fine sir! it was mistake in the selector i used double quotes in inspect element and then  apply same in  script and it works. So nice of you